# PointCloud Input to costmap_2d

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to add an additional PointCloud to the costmap_2d list of things to avoid (when doing PR2 navigation). I have added the proper information to the observation_sources parameter.

However, my PointCloud is not being avoided properly, despite the move_base node subscribing to the topic. When comparing my PointCloud messages to the `/ground_object_cloud` PointCloud data, I noticed that that PointCloud had four Channels of extra data: intensities, index, distances,  and stamps. Are these necessary input for costmap_2d, and if so, what do they mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12755/pointcloud-input-to-costmap_2d/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-01-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It turned out that the problem was not the parameters Lorenz mentioned (although he helped me narrow down the possibilities, for which I'm grateful). It turns out that just changing the frame helped.

I had originally been trying to add points in the `/map` frame ([related to my previous question](http://answers.ros.org/question/3537/custom-costmap-values)) which wasn't being processed by the cost map. I changed the node that was publishing the points to translate them to `/base_laser_link` and that fixed the problem, at least for now (in that it is taking the points into consideration, even if it sometimes causes problems).

I haven't dug into the code yet to figure out if that is a bug or a feature yet.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [skynet](https://answers.ros.org/users/33478/skynet/) on 2018-04-05**:
Is there any chance you can post your .yaml file for this? I am attempting to get costmap_2d to subscribe to /kinect2/hd/points but it seems my parameters are not correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We were using PointClouds that contain only points and no additional channels without a problem. My guess would rather be that the other observation sources maybe clear the points of your cloud again. I would first uncomment all observation sources but your additional point cloud. If that works, you can start playing around with the parameters `observation_persistence`, `clearing` and `marking`.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-01-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2012-01-26**:
I forgot about the clearing bit. Thanks for the tip,